# How to denote the foreign key mapping in hbase

Tags: hbase

Someone please help me understand how the Hbase works internally.

Can the value of a column refer to a key of another table?

For example:

Suppose i have a Student table with subjectId as a foreign key and the Subject table has the id as a primay key, then how would the representation be?
How can we map the Student and Subject together?

Answer (score 3):

**Someone please help me understand how the HBase works internally.**

This is something really big which can't be explained here completely. Please refer [this](http://hbase.apache.org/book/book.html) link for more detail.

**Can the value of a column refer to a key of another table?**

A column can definitely store the key of another row in the same or another table. You have to read this value from the first table and then go to the second table in order to fetch the row(if both the rows are in different tables).

**For example:
Suppose i have a Student table with subjectId as a foreign key and the Subject table has the id as a primary key, then how would the representation be? How can we map the Student and Subject together?**

Looks like you have misunderstood HBase. It doesn't work like traditional RDBMSs. There is no notion of Primary key, Composite key or Foreign key when you work with HBase. You can treat the rowkey as the primary key though. Rows are lexicographically sorted based on these rowkeys.

Coming back to your question. You could have 2 column families in your table, 1 for student and another for subject. In this manner you could access anything without having to move from one table to another.

HTH

---

In response to your comments :

You can either have a table with just 1 column family which will contain all the columns together. Something like this :

[image]

Or, if you want a separation between these 2 kinds of data, you can have 1 table with 2 column families, 1 for student related data and 1 for subject related data, like this :

[image]

Use **studentID** as the rowkey since it'll be unique for each student. Now if you want to fetch :

**1. Get all the students who have applied for the subject data science :**
Use columnvalue filter to achieve this.

**1. List all the subjects for a particular student :** This is simple. Just a get on that particular row.

Keep on adding columns for each subject as a student applies for.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Tariq. My doubt is , how would i be able to retreive which subjects belong to the student? Where is the relation between them maintained? Say, Student belongs to Student Family with the column names as name, age and subjectid. Similarly Subject table has subject family and columnsTitle , Description and  studentid. How would the mapping between these 2 tables maintained?

Comment: You're welcome @priya. Could you please show me your schema, if you have?Or your data so that I can suggest something. That would be helpful in answer your question properly.

Comment: Student table

Columns :

Name
Age
Sex
Subject (Reference to Subject table)

Subject table

Columns : 

Subject name
Subject description
Student ids (Reference to Student table)

Suppose this is my table in terms of RDBMS 

If i need to design this in Hbase, how do u suggest i do it?

My requirement is that i should be able to retrive a list of all students with the subjects they have applied for and also to get a list of all subjects.

Comment: Would there be any advantage of splitting into multiple column family over maintaining all the columns in one table under one family?

Comment: I don't think you'll have much difference with such a small no. of columns.

Comment: According to my actual requirement I have a set of around 20 columns, But I dont think it is feasible to split it into multiple families since if I split the data size of the split families would be too small. So is it ok to include all the 20 columns under one table and one family?

Comment: It's absolutely fine.