# HBASE nested data model

Tags: hbase

HBASE Version : 0.94.10

New to NOSQL designing data model for primary care system. i have normalized sample DB relationship model e.g. HBASE-0.94.0

```
Patient table: 

============ 

1) Patient_id - PK 

2) Added_BY 

3) Gender 

4) Usual_GP
```

,

```
Patient Name table: [One to many relationship with patient [One] Name[Many]] 

1) Name_id 

2) Patient_id - FK 

3) Name_type 

4) First name 

5) Last Name 

6) Middle name
```

,

```
Patient address table: [One to many relationship with patient [One] address[Many]] 

1) Address_id 

2) Patient_id - FK 

3) Address_type 

4) Line1 

5) Line2 

6) Line 3 

7) Line 4 

8) Line 5
```

,

```
Patient Phone table: [One to many relationship with patient [One] Phone[Many]] 

1) Phone_id 

2) Patient_id - FK 

3) PhoneType 

4) Phoneno 

5) ext
```

,

```
Medication and other details 

1)Entry_id 

2)Patient_id - FK [One to many relationship with patient [One] Medication[Many]] 

3)Start_date 

4)End_date 

5)Code 

6)Medicine description 

7)Dosage details 

8) Number of authorised 

9) Number issued
```

For above Normalised data model i have created sample NoSQL data model below, i Hope data model works for Document base NOSQL. Need to convert below Data model in to HBASE column based data model, pls help me.

```
Patient :{Patient_id:22, 

              Added_by:Doctor1, 

              Gender:Male, 

              UsualGP: Doctor2, 

              PatName:[ 

              {NameType:Usual, FirstName:Hari, LastName:prasad,Middlename:' '}, 

              {NameType:Other, FirstName:John,LastName:prasad,Middlename:kenndy}  

              ] 

              PatAddr:[ 

              {AddType:Usual, Line1:2, Line2:Harrington road, Line3: near central, Line4:Newyork,Line5:NY008}, 

              {AddType:Tmp, Line1:2, Line2:Mylapore road, Line3: near Zoo, Line4:WashingtonDC,Line5:WA00098} 

              ] 

              PatPhone:[ 

              {PhoneType:Usual, Phoneno:4453443344, ext:099}, 

              {PhoneType:Tmp, Phoneno:9198332342343, ext:} 

              ] 

              PatMedication:[ 

              {MedStardate:'01/01/2013', MedEndDate:'', Code:'Snomode', MedDesc:'Paracetmol', DosDet:'Take 2 daily', Noauth: 5, Issue: 3}, 

              {MedStardate:'01/05/2013', MedEndDate:'01/05/2013', Code:'readcode', MedDesc:'Avil', DosDet:'Take 1 daily', Noauth: 3, Issue: 1}, 

              {MedStardate:'01/10/2013', MedEndDate:'24/10/13', Code:'readcode', MedDesc:'Metacin', DosDet:'Take 2 daily', Noauth: 5, Issue: 3}, 

              ] 

             }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and read this first please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask Show us your attempts also.

Comment: Why HBase?! it was made for non-relational database use!..

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, HBase is for non-relational data. However, you can still use it for this purpose. First, you should define column families. There is no need for column names since it is in columnar form.

Having those columns in the same column family increases the performance. Therefore, one column family would be good. In addition to that, having column and column family names short is also another performance issue. If you can, name these columns and column variables with one or two letters.

However, you can not use foreign keys as it is. What i mean is that, you can store the id of another table in a column but you can not directly check whether it exists or not. Instead, you should go to this table and check it manually.

I hope this explanation will help you. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057285/how-to-denote-the-foreign-key-mapping-in-hbase) for more details.